# Employee Snooping

Tags: privacy, attack-prevention, access-control

I just got hired at this SW tech company with a few IT gurus in it. There is a clever genius that is suspect. He obtained my personal home email address I use. It was obtained from company communication during the hiring process. He some how set up a snooping system that is covertly social engineered in one of the yahoo email servers. I think he can target a specific email address and quietly collect messages read from the email server that is sent in the path without detection. Because I have used this one email to communicate with my Dad, he now has my Dad’s email address as well. I'm afraid that even if I switch to another email provider like Gmail that has better encryption capabilities, the evil genius will still get a hold of my messages due to the fact that he will merely intercept them from my Dad's yahoo email server system during continued communications.

I believe this SW company I work for condones this evil genius's actions and activities as they use him and his services as part of an internal company security by knowing if any of their employees are committing espionage, illegal activities or are planning to find another job else where and such.

Now I'm wondering if this evil genius can even track my ip address derived from the email headers, and use them to record a tracking history on every website  that I hit. I do have DHCP but my ip address stays static for the whole duration that I start my online session. And especially right after I read my emails my ip address can be stripped from the header and freshly tracked for as long as the session lasts. All he would need to do is to find a way to engineer his way to snoop into the nearest gateway in my local ISP system taken from the email header. And then he could snoop for my ip address that is attached to any outbound domain address and collect a website hit history.

I'm not a SW guru or have much in-depth knowledge in the IT industry, but I do know enough to make my way around. I just wanted to know from the expert gurus themselves who are in the light and part of the Force as opposed to the evil genius that is on the dark side, if the technical aspects to all of this are very possible? Or would this require too difficult a level of skill to accomplish? And if so, how could I successfully counter this without having to go to the lengths of implementing GPG?

Also, even if the emails I pull from the email server are encrypted, are the headers used in the transport layer also encrypted? Or will this still be a vulnerability in the system?

Comment: You've outlined the background well, now state your objective clearly. Do you want to prevent the attacker seeing your email headers? Obtaining your IP address? Be specific.

Comment: The light/dark analogy may be a little too lyrical for my tastes. All this is very interesting, but what evidence do you actually have that he accessed your personal e-mail? 

Your address (or your dad's) is something a Google search will probably provide. And if he did break into your e-mail account, why would it mean that he has access to Yahoo!'s servers? Maybe you created an account on the company's website to apply, and used the same password as your e-mail address.

Comment: You have two completely different questions here. Are you worried about him snooping on you while you are at work, or while you are at home? It sounds like he is snooping on your work traffic, this would in no way give him access to your home network.

Comment: In civilized countries spying on personal email accounts is illegal for a company.

Comment: as scuzzy pointed out, you don't currently have a clear question. The information you have provided doesn't really hang together (as the commenters above have mentioned) - so please edit the post to clearly state what you are trying to ask, then we may be able to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are concerned that you are being snooped on at work.

Generally your place of employment has good and sufficient justification for snooping on all network traffic, namely that they are concerned you may exfiltrate confidential information - either company IP, or protected customer data, which they are required by Data Protection law, or Financial or health regulations (SEC, FSA, HIPA etc) to protect from rogue employees.

- ***Don't use work computers for personal use. Period.***

If you **really** need to access personal email at work, use your phone, on your phone's data plan - **not** the work Wi-Fi network.

The UK's Information Commissioner's Office guidance is here (section 3):

- http://ico.org.uk/for_organisations/data_protection/topic_guides/~/media/documents/library/Data_Protection/Detailed_specialist_guides/the_employment_practices_code.pdf

Ernst & Young have a good presentation on current EU case law:

- http://www.ey.com/publication/vwluassets/employee_data/%24file/employee_data.pdf

Finally:

- ***If you don't trust your employer, get a new employer***.

Comment: To be honest this is more a legal issue than anything else. If you are in the EU you are not allowed to snoop traffic of employees and review it manually. You can have an AUP for personal use and even when you are not allowed to use your computer or the infrastructure for personal use, once there is a folder called "personal" your employer is not allowed to check it.

Comment: @LucasKauffman, that is not correct. If you are told your use can be monitored, monitoring is lawful. http://www.adviceguide.org.uk/england/life/employment/monitoring_at_work.htm "You should bear in mind that these circumstances cover almost every situation where your employer might want to monitor your electronic communications, except where the monitoring is for purely private or spiteful reasons."

Comment: Monitoring is lawful as long as the data monitored is not private. Refer to EU Data Protection Directive (95/46/EC). It is not permitted for an employer to access private files and e-mail messages in general. However, taking into account the aforementioned information obligation, an employer may monitor internet activity and email correspondence where there is concrete suspicion of criminal or disloyal behaviour, a violation of internal guidelines, or for security reasons.

Comment: And the employee should be clearly informed up front about this.

Comment: @LucasKauffman, the directive isn't the law, it requires member states to pass laws which meet its requirements. It allows member states to make (large) exceptions to, for example, protect the rights of others. So you can be monitored at work if this is an exception your member state has made to protect others **which is the case here in the UK** because obviously if you as part of your job have access to personal data belonging to others then the employer has a duty to take **proactive** measures to prevent you from stealing it. Monitoring is essentially compulsory under these circumstances.